# Atualização do Jenkins

Tags: linux, atualização, jenkins

Tenho o Jenkins instalado num servidor com  Debian 8. Gostaria de saber qual o procedimento correto para atualização da versão. Na documentação atual, não especifica o procedimento de atualização. Em pesquisa no StackOverFlow em inglês, só encontrei respostas antigas (2012, 13, 14), nas quais tinha até documentação oficial de como fazer (mas a versão atual vai para a documentação de instalação).
Eu acredito que funcionaria pelo comando: 

 `sudo apt-get upgrade jenkins`
Mas eu não tenho certeza se é o melhor caminho ou o mais indicado.
Se alguém souber se este é um procedimento correto ou se há outros, agradeço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wget    http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/latest/jenkins.war
cp jenkins.war /usr/lib/jenkins
systemsctl stop jenkins
systemsctl start jenkins
```

É um processo simples, só trocar o .war pela versão mais nova. Se o jenkins não está instalado como serviço, basta acessar o navegador e colocar um `/restart` no final da URL base do jenkins

Comment: Muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 1):

Outro caminho, além deste da resposta que aceitei é seguir o caminho de como se fosse instalar novamente, descrito em https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/ (específico para debian/ubuntu).

Primeiro adicione esta chave ao sistema:

```
    wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Depois acesse /etc/apt/sources.list com o seu editor de text (eu uso vim ou nano) com sudo e adicione a linha a seguir ao arquivo:

```
    deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/
```

E finalmente, os comandos para instalação:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

Assim eu consegui atualizar sem problemas.